# How pass data from ModalService into component

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to use ngx-bootstrap-modal to pass data from a modal service into a modal component. The [examples](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) show this:

```
this.modalService.show(ModalContentComponent, {initialState});
```

But it doesn't show how the `ModalContentComponent` actually consumes that state. I've played around in a debugger and I never see my component getting that data.

How do I access it from the component?

Answer (score 9):

Here, in parentComponent where initialState data is being sent using config param in modalService.show:

```
const initialState = {
      data: "Test Data"
    };
    this.modalService.show(ModalContentComponent, {initialState});
```

Access the data in ModalContentComponent by simply defining exact same named variable, i.e., `data: string;`
You will be able to access value of data in ModalContentComponent.html and ModalContentComponent.ts.

Answer (score 6):

At the stage of creating a modal, every property from `initialState` is copied to the component that you pass as a modal content.

For example, if your `initialState` looks like this:

```
const initialState = {
   list: [
     'Open a modal with component',
     'Pass your data',
     'Do something else',
     '...',
     'PROFIT!!!'
   ],
   title: 'Modal with component',
   closeBtnName: 'Close'
 };
```

Then all these properties are copied to your modal content component and they're accessible there and you can use them in your template or `ngOnInit` as usual. In general, these properties are like `@Input`.

Example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9n2zck?file=app/service-component.ts

Comment: how to pass the id? i'm getting undefined 

  this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ConfirmationModalComponent, { initialState });
    this.modalRef.content.itemId = '2';

  ngOnInit(): void {   
    console.log(this.itemId);   
  }

Comment: Properties of a modal component that were set after `modalService.show()` won't be available in `ngOnInit`. If you want to get access to this data in `ngOnInit`, use `initialState` as I shown above

Comment: Just to add something that I struggled with. After showing the modal using the service `modalService.show(MyModalComponent, initialState)` then the initialState can be injected in MyModalComponent's constructor like this `constructor(modal: BsModalRef, options: ModalOptions)`

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the `BsModalRef content`
Like

my-modal.component.ts

```
export class MyModalComponent {
  public myContent;
  constructor(){}
}
```

calling your modal from some other component

```
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
...
    public modalRef: BsModalRef;

    constructor(public modalService: BsModalService){}

    public openModal() {
       this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(MyModalComponent);
       this.modalRef.content.myContent= 'My Modal Content';
    }
...
```

Answer (score 2):

In angular 11 this is working fine for me

In parent component

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef} from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef, ModalOptions, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { ModalChildComponent } from '../../shared/modal-child/modal-child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  bsModalRef: BsModalRef;
  
  constructor(    private modalService: BsModalService
  ) { 
    this.openModalWithComponent();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

     public openModalWithComponent() {
      let initialState = { message: 'popup message', title:'popup title'};
      let modalConfig = { animated: true, keyboard: true, backdrop: true, ignoreBackdropClick: false };
      /* this is how we open a Modal Component from another component */
      this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ModalCalendlyComponent, 
        Object.assign({}, modalConfig, {class: 'modal-sm', initialState
        })
        );
    }

  }
```

In child component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef, ModalOptions, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-child',
  templateUrl: './modal-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-child.component.css']
})
export class ModalChildComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
    public bsModalRef: BsModalRef, 
    public options: ModalOptions
  ) {
    console.log(this.options.initialState);
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't yet comment on IlyaSurmay's answer...his solution works in 2.0.2 (but not in 2.0.0).

Comment: i had version 1.9.3 and did not work. after upgrading ngx-bootstrap to version 2.0.5 it started working

Answer (score 0):

if you used `ngx-bootstrap/modal` then you can do this way.

// Parent Component

```
let initialState = { message: 'This is test' };
this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(Component, { initialState });

this.modalRef.content.action.take(1).subscribe((value) => {
  console.log(value) // here you will get the value
});
```

// Modal Component

```
import { BsModalRef, ModalOptions, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Output() action = new EventEmitter();

 constructor(public options: ModalOptions)

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.options.initialState); // here you will get the value
  }

 closedModal() {
    this.modalService.hide(1);
    this.action.emit(true);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In ngx-bootstrap version 8, this has been changed. Now you can get the intialState object value through the **BsModalService**

In the service, you would have to call:

```
export class DynamicComponentService {

  modalRef: BsModalRef;

  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService, private modalOptions: ModalOptions) { }

  show(template: TemplateRef<any>): void {           

    const initialState = { message: "hello" };
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, {initialState});
  }
}
```

Then, in the child modal, you can get the value like this:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {   
  

  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {
    
    console.log('OPTIONS', this.modalService.config.initialState);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
  }
}
```

Hope it helps someone. I've been trying all other answers, but none works for me until I dig deeper into the object and see it myself

Answer (score -1):

set `@Input()` parameter in the popup component to access the property in initialState

In Parent Component:

```
const initialState = { message: 'popup message', title:'popup title'};
let bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ConfirmPopupComponent, Object.assign({}, this.modalConfig, { class: 'modal-sm', initialState })
```

In confirmPopupComponent:

```
@Input() message: string = 'Message here...'; // we can set the default value also
@Input() title: string = 'default title';
```

Comment: what is this.modalConfig ? or how to set value of this.modalConfig ?